# Can I record video and then make a call while recording?

Tags: iphone, video, recording

This is so not me:

[image]

But I was curious if there was a way to call 911 while recording, so, anyone who *is* like this can at least have an option. :-)

Comment: It is possible, you can just hack your phone. Idk if jailbroken phones can do this or not, but physically it should be possible. Is it worth all the trouble you'd have to go through? Not really (imo).

Comment: @theonlygusti, agreed. Might make an interesting feature request for the future though. [This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lYSax0aHVw&t=0m13s) could have used it. Can't believe people like this exist... Also, listen to how the newsreader pronounces "fiery." ^_^

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it. Such a feature might be unlawful because it allows recording of conversations...

Comment: I understand the privacy concerns for making regular calls while recording, but an exemption for emergency numbers would be very useful (for other reasons than pictured above). If you're the sole witness of a crime, it would be beneficial to both record what's happening and alert the police at the same time. That's a tough decision to make in an already tense situation – to either delay calling for help or give up on possibly valuable evidence.

Answer (score 2):

No, as soon as you receive a call or initiate a call the video recording is stopped.

With an active call it's not possible to record a video at all.

I have tested this with iOS 9.3.x, iOS 10.3.x and iOS 11.0.x.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know if the iPhone has forceable glitches for certain features? I remember being able to have two tabs open on Safari. One YouTube, and one, say, news, and if I tapped the play button on YouTube and then almost instantaneously but slightly after press the news tab I could listen to YouTube music while reading the news. Is there any way to force it via a glitch like that?

Comment: @uwnojpjm There are no glitches that I’m aware of.